# How to print child categories of sub categories in hierarchical order

Tags: php, recursion, logic

I am trying to print categories in hierarchical order no matter how deep they are, I have been trying but success only for second level, what if they are 3 or four level deep. I want them to print in drop down like

```
Tasks
 -hard task
 --simple task

Notes
 -hard note
 --simple note
 ---easy note
```

records

```
$records = array(   
array( 'id'=>'1',  'parent'=>'0', 'name'=>'Tasks' ),    
array( 'id'=>'2',  'parent'=>'0', 'name'=>'Notes' ),    

array( 'id'=>'3', 'parent'=>'1', 'name'=>'hard task' ),
array( 'id'=>'4', 'parent'=>'3', 'name'=>'simple task' ),

array( 'id'=>'5', 'parent'=>'2', 'name'=>'hard note' ),
array( 'id'=>'6', 'parent'=>'5', 'name'=>'simple note' ),
array( 'id'=>'7', 'parent'=>'6', 'name'=>'easy note' ),
);
```

code I am trying

```
function print_records($records){

foreach ($records as $rec){

    echo $rec['name'];
    $get_parent = $rec['parent'];
    get_sub_cat($get_parent);
  }
}


function get_sub_cat($get_parent){

foreach ($get_parent as $rec){

    echo $rec['name'];
    $get_sub = $rec['parent'];
    get_sub_child_cat($get_parent);
  } 
}
```

here I am completely lost! I have seen recursion but not sure how to use in this case

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called a recursion. The idea is like this:

```
function printLeafs($node){
  echo $node->title;

  $leafs = getLeafs($node);
  foreach ($leafs as $leaf){
    printLeafs($leaf);
  }
}
```

Funny, there is a same qustion at the same time: [PHP Print indefinite categories tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970574/php-print-indefinite-categories-tree)

**Update:**

The working solution is (to be executed from command line):

```
<?php

$records = array(
    array( 'id'=>'1',  'parent'=>'0', 'name'=>'Tasks' ),
    array( 'id'=>'2',  'parent'=>'0', 'name'=>'Notes' ),

    array( 'id'=>'3', 'parent'=>'1', 'name'=>'hard task' ),
    array( 'id'=>'4', 'parent'=>'3', 'name'=>'simple task' ),

    array( 'id'=>'5', 'parent'=>'2', 'name'=>'hard note' ),
    array( 'id'=>'6', 'parent'=>'5', 'name'=>'simple note' ),
    array( 'id'=>'7', 'parent'=>'6', 'name'=>'easy note' ),
);

printLeafs($records, 0);

function printLeafs($records, $id, $depth = 0){
    if ($id) {
        $node = getNode($records, $id);
        echo str_pad('', $depth, '-') . $node['name'] . "\n";
    }

    $leafs = getLeafs($records, $id);
    foreach ($leafs as $leaf){
        printLeafs($records, $leaf['id'], $depth + 1);
    }
}

function getNode($records, $id){
    foreach ($records as $rec){
        if ($rec['id'] == $id){
            return $rec;
        }
    }

    throw new \Exception('id "' . $id . '" not found');
}

function getLeafs($records, $parent_id){
    $result = [];
    foreach ($records as $rec){
        if ($rec['parent'] == $parent_id){
            $result[] = $rec;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Also i would recommend using objects.

Comment: Oh ya that's funny what a co incidence

Comment: can you please do it in my way for better understanding, I have been trying but perfect solution will make my day